# Is it possible to build a simple frontend to Google-cloud-sql with Google forms and Google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

As we are evaluating the migration of our database to Google-cloud and use of Google Apps, I'm wondering if it is possible to use Google-forms and Google-apps-script to create simple forms that let our users populate our database ?

The same question for using Google-spreadsheet and Google-apps-script to create Reports that export data from the database to blank Google-spreadsheet ?

If yes, how difficult would that be ? ( I got experience in programming with ruby, php, VB-script )

Comment: It's possible, but the 'difficulty' is probably best evaluated by you and your firm. You could use the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) to capture the form data, and the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) or [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/) to connect to the Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: I don't really know that much about hooking up to the data bases in GS but anything you can do in php/html in terms of forms you can definitely do in google scripts and hooking up a button to the server in as simple as this: <input type="button" value="Do It" onClick="google.script.run.thenameofyourfunction" /> and that's it.  Of course you can add class and id and do it via jquery or if you wish you can use AngularJS.  I don't know that much about their forms but building UI's in GS is just as powerful as PHP and HTML and the server hookup is a lot easier to achieve and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use Google Forms to collect data into Sheets, and then use Apps Script to trigger on form submit and insert new records into Cloud SQL.  This answer was a great help to me recently in doing something similar:

[Google Form data to store in cloud SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787717/google-form-data-to-store-in-cloud-sql-database)

Medium difficulty? The hardest part was then building a reporting application on top of Cloud SQL with Google App Engine.  More than that that I couldn't say for your situation, since I used Python.

Comment: "building a reporting application on top of Cloud SQL with Google App Engine"  Any pointers on how to do that?