# Google Forms writing to SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, jdbc, google-forms

I am currently trying to get my Google Form to write directly to my SQL Server database when a form is submitted. I have successfully connected the form to the database using the script editor but it only writes to the database when I hard code the value. How do I read the input directly from the form and insert it into the database? My code is as follows:

```
function handleFormSubmit( event ) {
 // var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
var conn = 
Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://dbname.database.windows.net:1433;" +
 "databaseName=dbname;user=UN;password=PW;");
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO TemporaryTable '
      + '(FirstName, LastName) values (?, ?)');
  //stmt.setString(1, 'Timestamp');
  stmt.setString(1, event.namedValues['FirstName']);
  stmt.setString(2, event.namedValues['LastName']);
  stmt.execute();
}
```

Comment: Please check with console.log(event), if the data is where you expect it. By the way, is the database connection in the client or on the server delivering the page?

Comment: You can take a look in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787717/google-form-data-to-store-in-cloud-sql-database

Comment: had tried the exact same thing @Myonara ... the event is undefined ... also getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined.` any advise?