# Replicating Google Form data to Cloud SQL

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql, google-forms

```
// Connection to Google form
var form = FormApp.openById('*********************************');

// Connection variable
var instanceConnectionName = '*****:*******:*******';
var user = 'root';
var userPwd = '**********';
var db = '********';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;

// Receive form response and replicate to a row in SQL table
function handleFormSubmit( event ) {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO eform '
      + '(Timestamp, Email, Department, Acknowledge) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');
  stmt.setString(1, event.namedValues['Timestamp']);
  stmt.setString(2, event.namedValues['Email']);
  stmt.setString(2, event.namedValues['Department']);
  stmt.setString(3, event.namedValues['Acknowledge']);
  stmt.execute();

}
```

I tried the above code to save Google Form data to one of my Cloud SQL instance but getting this error:

[image]

Any idea why? anyway is that the correct way to do it? I believe there is no spelling error in the connection variable and I stuck ...

Comment: Are you defining your jdbcURL as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#languages)?

`String jdbcUrl = String.format(
    "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s"
        + "&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false",
    databaseName,
    instanceConnectionName);` I think your URL looks a bit different to this

Comment: Got this error when try using your code: `TypeError: Cannot find function format in object function String() { [native code for String.String, arity=1] }` ... btw I'm using App Scipt from the Google Form and using following [code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl-username-password)

Comment: and also referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791522/9426876) ... yet failed to establish the connection ... I'm afraid there's some step that I've missed somewhere?

Comment: My mistake, that code is for Java and I see now that Apps Script uses a jdbc wrapper for Javascript. Have you tried using the recommended method provided by that package? [jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(url, userName, password)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getcloudsqlconnectionurl-username-password)

Comment: has tried that one like this `var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://" + instanceConnectionName + "/" + db);` yet still getting the same error ..

Comment: Could you share the details of that error?